# Passing column name from one cursor to select statement of another cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

I have two cursor c11 and c2 .I have two tables compare1 and compare2.Both having same columns but values are different. I want to pass result of c1 to c2 cursor. I am fetching column names of a table from user_tab_columns. I want to pass the column name to get difference of unique records between compare 1 and compare2 tables. But the column names from c1 is not passed to c2.Please find the code which I have tried.

```
DECLARE
   COL         VARCHAR2 (200);
  OUTRECORD   VARCHAR2 (200);
   CURSOR c1  IS
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM all_tab_columns
   WHERE     table_name = 'COMPARE1';            
CURSOR c2( col varchar(200))   IS--col is the column names from c1 
   (SELECT DISTINCT COL
            FROM COMPARE1
          MINUS
          SELECT DISTINCT COL
            FROM COMPARE2);
BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO COL;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (COL);
    OPEN c2(col);--col Is not passing to 2nd cursor
    LOOP
      FETCH c2 INTO OUTRECORD;--outrecord is empty is col is not passed to 2nd cursor
      INSERT INTO RESULT
          VALUES ('B001',
                  'COMPARE',
                  '2018',
                  COL,
                  OUTRECORD,--empy value
                  'NOT PRESENT IN 2017');
      COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c2;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c1;
END;
```

Help me in passing values to c1.Thanks in advance

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: We are using Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason why your code is not working as you expect it to is because you're passing the column name from the first cursor into the second cursor as a literal value.

So, when you do the minus in the second cursor, you're comparing if one string is the same as that string, meaning no rows will be returned. I.e. it is essentially:

```
select 'x' from some_table
minus
select 'x' from some_other_table;
```

To get around this, you would need to use dynamic sql - here's an example using a cursor and a ref cursor:

```
DECLARE
  rc        SYS_REFCURSOR;
  outrecord VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  FOR r1 IN (SELECT column_name col
             FROM   all_tab_columns
             WHERE  table_name = 'COMPARE1')
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(r1.col);

    OPEN rc FOR 'SELECT '||r1.col||' col'||CHR(10)||
                'FROM   compare1'||CHR(10)||
                'MINUS'||CHR(10)||
                'SELECT '||r1.col||' col'||CHR(10)||
                'FROM   compare2';

    LOOP
      FETCH rc
        INTO outrecord; 

      EXIT WHEN rc%NOTFOUND;

      INSERT INTO RESULT -- you should list the columns being inserted into here
      VALUES
        ('B001',
         'COMPARE',
         '2018',
         r1.col,
         outrecord,
         'NOT PRESENT IN 2017');
      COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE rc;
END;
/
```

You can see that I've converted the looping round the first cursor into a cursor-for-loop, rather than explicitly fetching each row. That way, you don't have to worry about checking you've reached the end of the rows or closing the cursor. The inner loop through the second cursor I've added in the missing `exit when rc%notfound` clause.

Note also that I have removed the `distinct`s from your minus query - `minus` already distincts the rows, so there is no need to explicitly state it.

However, what you've got going there is a row-by-row insert, which is not the best approach at all - you should instead be doing all the work in a single insert statement, which you can see below:

```
BEGIN
  FOR r1 IN (SELECT column_name col
             FROM   all_tab_columns
             WHERE  table_name = 'COMPARE1')
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(r1.col);

    execute immediate 'INSERT INTO RESULT'||CHR(10)|| -- you should list the columns being inserted into here
                      'SELECT ''B001'','||CHR(10)||
                      '       ''COMPARE'','||CHR(10)||
                      '       ''2018'','||CHR(10)||
                      '       '''||r1.col||''','||CHR(10)||
                      '       '||r1.col||CHR(10)||
                      'FROM   compare1'||CHR(10)||
                      'MINUS'||CHR(10)||
                      'SELECT ''B001'','||CHR(10)||
                      '       ''COMPARE'','||CHR(10)||
                      '       ''2018'','||CHR(10)||
                      '       '''||r1.col||''','||CHR(10)||
                      '       '||r1.col||CHR(10)||
                      'FROM   compare2';

  END LOOP;    END;
/
```

N.B. untested.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer :) . Now I got the point.. But I am getting identifier is too long error for the select statement. Is there any way to get rid of it

Comment: Apologies; I'd missed out the `execute immediate` from my final pl/sql block. As for the error message you're getting, you might find aliasing your columns helps, e.g. `'SELECT ''B001'','||CHR(10)||` becomes `'SELECT ''B001'' some_alias_name,'||CHR(10)||

Comment: For the first solution, if I try using alias name ,I am getting error saying 'expected USing'

Comment: There were some errors in my first pl/sql block that I have hopefully corrected now. I have no idea why an error saying "unexpected using" would appear - I suggest you copy across the full error message.

Comment: ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Comment: ORA-06512: at line 11

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some tweaks, and have tested both solutions as best I can. Neither of them gives me an error, especially not the identifier is too long error (which I can only think you're getting because you're trying to select a column that's greater than 30 characters, but given you're getting that from all_tab_columns, that's unlikely. I suggest you raise another question giving the exact code that you're getting the error with.